# v-model on input that dynamically changes value by other script ?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two input that store lat and lng from google map script, if the user changes the marker's position => these two inputs get the lat and lng that the user pecked, so I wanna get the value of these two inputs, I tried v-model but it didnt work I actually noticed that the v-model will be fired only if I changed the value of these input by typing or pasting something in. 
Is there a way that I can get the value of these inputs (like on-change) to my Vue instance?

Comment: What mechanism is changing the inputs?

Comment: just a js script putting the values in the inputs when the marker of the map change position

Answer (score 9):

To trigger Vue.js to read your input's value after it changes dynamically from an external script, you have to call:

```
document.querySelector('#element-id').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

on your element. This works on both `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements. For `<select>` elements you would have to call:

```
document.querySelector('#element-id').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch your two variables, and assign the value to the new one.

Comment: what variables?? from the map script?

Answer (score 0):

Watch your variables using *watch* properties:

HTML:

```
<div id="el">
  <form>
    <input v-model="foo">
    <input v-model="bar">
  </form>
  <p>{{ foo }}</p>
  <p>{{ bar }}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
   el: "#el",
   data: {
       foo: '',
       bar: ''
   },
   watch: {
      foo: function(value) {
         this.foo = value
       },
      bar: function(value) {
         this.bar = value
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: yess normally that wil work, but not if the inputs change value by other script not by the user keyboard, I think that this dosnot exist on vuejs ..

Comment: What does not exist in vuejs?! The values will change if the value of the input change (DOM) and also if you try your "script". Try the code or gives us snippet.

Comment: The problem here is that the script of google map change the value of the input but the v-model dosent fire, the v-model fires only when I type somthing in that in input but not when the script of the map changes its value

Comment: So using watch you can detect the onchange event!

Comment: `watch` doesn't work for me — reading the docs i believe it's for a different purpose (watching changes to the vue instance's data attributes). The op and I want the v-model to be changed by a script that knows nothing about Vuejs, and is simply directly manipulating the input's value, which doesn't fire any change/keydown etc events. @brahimm did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @jeff-h , no I did not find a solution for this one, I think I tried a work around, but I couldn't detect a change on `Vuejs` instance, made by external script that knows nothing about `Vuejs`