# vuejs model not updating when using an address lookup

Tags: vue.js

I am using a postcode search service to populate address form fields.

[image: example of search]

When an address is selected, the form fields are populated correctly, i.e. town is in town field etc.

Problem is, it doesn't update the model.

```
<div class="form-group address">
    <label for="postcodeFormField">Postcode *</label>
    <input name="postcode" v-model="contact.postcode" type="text" class="form-control" id="postcodeFormField" placeholder="SW7 3RX" required>
</div>
```

If I manually type into the fields, it does update the model. But the address data which displays in the form fields after an address is selected, is not being reflected in the model.

Comment: How are you populating the form fields from the `<select>` dropdown?

Comment: There is no <select> dropdown. There is some javascript code on the page which enables this data to display as shown in the screenshot. My form fields are mapped in the postcode search providers' tool to their fields, enabling the address lines to appear in my fields, in the correct fields.

Comment: Then, show us how you're populating these fields when the dropdown is selected.

Comment: I am not populating them in my code. My fields are defined in the providers tool. https://www.loqate.com/resources/support/setup-guides/ address verification video, 1 minute 30 seconds in (its about 10-20seconds of the video to explain what I am doing visually)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Terry, but I am not sure how I could make it clearer. Since posting I have seen one other post which appears to be the same issue with a different JS source. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351617/v-model-on-input-that-dynamically-changes-value-by-other-script

Comment: “Not sure how to make it clearer”: [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Add a ref to the input i.e `ref="postcodeFormField"`

Hit a method on submit button `@click="myMethod()"`

In that method:`this.$refs.postcodeFormField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`

Comment: its `ref=""` not `refs` and if you have a method that doesn't require a specifici set of params you dont need to add the `()` at the end

Comment: Correct, I typed refs when I meant to type ref. Updated to reflect this mistake. However the parentheses () seem to be required for me still to hit the method successfully, regardless of passing params or not.

Comment: If it is the only method I call on @click it works, like @click="methodOne", however I do something like this: @click="methodOne(); methodTwo(); step = 1;" :disabled="checkDisabled" and just removing the parentheses to make it  @click="methodOne; methodTwo(); step = 1;" :disabled="checkDisabled" results in never hitting the method

Comment: well yeah if you are using multiple calls in one event-binding you cant pass the reference.